# url getting added to the original url

Tags: html, url

Recently a webservice has been setup at my work place for the following, say for example,

```
http://texting.testing.myweburl.com/
```

In my code, when we access the above URL, a HTML page is shown which has some web URLS in it. say for example, the page displays the following:

```
AT & T Website is : www.att.com
```

And I have defined it in my code as follows:

```
AT & T Website is : <a href= "www.att.com">www.att.com</a>
```

So, when I click on the weblink which is **www.att.com** , instead getting directed to AT & T Website,

the above URL is getting added to my original URL like the following:

```
http://texting.testing.myweburl.com/www.att.com
```

which I don't want. Recently the DNS entry has been setup for the URL `http://texting.testing.myweburl.com/` .

So is there something wrong that could have done while setting up webservice?

Comment: Put http:// in front of www

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add http:// , so try this

```
<a href= "http://www.att.com">www.att.com</a>
```